# Why DSB SY in _fiq_handler cause data inconsistency？

Tags: assembly, embedded, interrupt, arm64, memory-barriers

My system is an AArch6 single-core system.
I have two timer interrupt handlers, `apb_timer_irq_isr0` and `apb_timer_irq_isr1`, which are executed every 500ms and 1000ms respectively.

Two variables, `isr0` and `isr1`, are defined to keep track of the execution count of the two functions. Normally, there should be a doubling relationship between them, but in a certain scenario, there is a quadrupling relationship, and even 2.7 times.

```
//If printing is added simultaneously in two interrupt service routines, then isr0 and isr1 are in a 2x relationship.
uint16_t isr0 = 0;
uint16_t isr1 = 0;
 static void apb_timer_irq_isr0(int IntNum,void *param)
 {
      _apb_timer_clear_irq(1, 0, 0);
      isr0++;
      trace("isr0 %d\n", isr0);
  }
  static void apb_timer_irq_isr1(int IntNum,void *param)
  {
      _apb_timer_clear_irq(2, 1, 0);
      isr1++;
      trace("isr1 %d\n", isr1);
  }

// However, if only one function adds printing, it will result in a fourfold relationship. like this:
 static void apb_timer_irq_isr0(int IntNum,void *param)
 {
      _apb_timer_clear_irq(1, 0, 0);
      isr0++;
  }
  static void apb_timer_irq_isr1(int IntNum,void *param)
  {
      _apb_timer_clear_irq(2, 1, 0);
      isr1++;
      trace("isr0 %d\n", isr0);
      trace("isr1 %d\n", isr1);
  }
```

This issue has been resolved, but the cause is unknown, and it is uncertain whether it will have any other impacts.
the solution is: Comment out the DSB SY in the fiq_handler.

```
fiq_handler:
    /* Save volatile registers. */
    STP     X0, X1, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X2, X3, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X4, X5, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X6, X7, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X8, X9, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X10, X11, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X12, X13, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X14, X15, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X16, X17, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X18, X19, [SP, #-0x10]!
    STP     X29, X30, [SP, #-0x10]!

#if defined( GUEST )
    MRS     X3, SPSR_EL1
    MRS     X2, ELR_EL1
#else
    MRS     X3, SPSR_EL3
    MRS     X2, ELR_EL3
#endif
    
    STP     X2, X3, [SP, #-0x10]!

    /* Call the C handler. */
    BL fiq_handler

    /* Disable interrupts. */
    MSR     DAIFSET, #3
//  DSB     SY        /*========Pay attention to this part.========*/
    ISB     SY

    /* Restore volatile registers. */
    LDP     X4, X5, [SP], #0x10  /* SPSR and ELR. */
#if defined( GUEST )
    MSR     SPSR_EL1, X5
    MSR     ELR_EL1, X4
#else
    MSR     SPSR_EL3, X5 /*_RB_ Assumes started in EL3. */
    MSR     ELR_EL3, X4
#endif
//  DSB     SY        /*========Pay attention to this part.========*/
    ISB     SY

    LDP     X29, X30, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X18, X19, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X16, X17, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X14, X15, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X12, X13, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X10, X11, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X8, X9, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X6, X7, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X4, X5, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X2, X3, [SP], #0x10
    LDP     X0, X1, [SP], #0x10

    //MSR   DAIFSET, #0
    ERET
#endif
```

but why？

Since my system is single-core, As far as I know, DSB should have little impact. I suspect it may be due to the cache?

Comment: That's AArch64 code, not ARM32.  `LDP` is AArch64, and register names like X29 and X30 are also specific to AArch64 state.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my oversight. yes, this is AArch64 code, and my system is AArch64 too.

Comment: I think `DSB SY` would at most make your ISRs slower but surely not negatively affect the visibility of the stores of a core w.r.t. to itself. Is it possible that the `ŧrace` macro/function with `DSB` present makes the ISR so slow that it would lose some interrupt? Can you move the calls to `trace` outside of the ISRs (e.g. in your main loop) while uncommenting the `DSB` instruction and see if the problem persists? The timer have pretty big periods so this seems unlikely but maybe it's worth trying.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I have tried the method you mentioned, adding print statements in the main loop. I called the delay_ms function. However, strangely, isr0 and isr1 became a 2.7 times relationship. When I tried removing the delay_ms function, it returned to the normal relationship. Additionally, there is another phenomenon: when I use `the flush_dcache_all()` function to flush the cache in `apb_timer_irq_isr0()`, it returns to normal. But when I use the `volatile` qualifier for isr0 and isr1, it doesn't work.@MargaretBloom